# Grub Rescue in Windows8 -Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub

I deleted 2 partitions on my hard disk and now I am unable to boot my pc. I searched and found that it is possible to boot without a CD, but the method is not working for me because I can't find the partition with the /boot directory.Each -ls (hd0,x) command says unknown file system. Please help.I am stuck for 7 hours now.

Comment: Ummm...which partitions did you delete? Depending on which partitions you deleted, it won't be easy to get it back, or maybe even impossible, depending on your system's disk layout.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe deleted 2 unnamed partitions.What to do ? I repeatedly get Unknown Filesystem Error

Comment: Unnamed partitions...according to Windows, or according to Linux?

Comment: Don't delete unknown partitions...it is possible that there isn't anything left to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore deleted partitions using "Testdisk" utility.

Any Linux live CD/USB could download and install Testdisk (if not already present).

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd